# MongoDB - How do I find and sort by the value of an object-attribute which is in an array field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with items that have an array named 'servicePlans', each servicePlan has a date. I want to sort on the date of a servicePlan with id = x.

For example:

```
[{
  _id: '1',
  servicePlans: [{
    _id: 'x1',
    date: '2017-01-02'
  },{
    _id: 'x2',
    date: '2017-01-01'
  }]
},{
  _id: '2',
  servicePlans: [{
    _id: 'x1',
    date: '2017-01-01'
  },{
    _id: 'x2',
    date: '2017-01-02'
  }]
}]
```

The result, when sorting on the date of servicePlan with id: 'x1', would be:

```
[{
  _id: '2',
  ...
},{
  _id: '1',
  ...
}]
```

Comment: I'm sure there is something in the FAQ here to the effect of *"Questions should not draw conclusions"*. Your question title and content are greatly at odds. What is it you actually have to do? So considering the data "as is" right now without changes, then what result are you trying to obtain for what purpose?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Each object has an array of servicePlans. I need to sort on the date of a specific servicePlan. Do you mean the aliasing of fields I'd like to have is drawing a conclusion? If so, I guess I should rephrase the question to aliasing instead of sorting, but this was just a guess.

Comment: What I mean is Is your question *"How do sort by the value of a date within an array field matching another property"* i.e Where "x" = 1. OR are you asking *"How do I create new fields in a document based on contents of my array?"*. Because your question makes a statement *"Sort on field in Object array"* and then draws to the conclusion by discussing *"Adding fields"*. So maybe it's just me, but I find that extremely confusing, and it makes it difficult to determine what to actually answer or advise on.

Comment: BTW. Your dates are "strings", which is not only a waste of byte space, but your "strings" are not lexically ordered ( ie should be YYY-MM-DD ) in order to be able to "sort" correctly in any event.

Comment: I'm sorry, I see now how the title could've been confusing, hope this makes more sense. The dates are just an example here, they are real dates in the db.

Comment: Dude. It's not so much the title it's the `servicePlan_x1_date: '2017-01-01',` stuff that's mostly confusing. So which one are we doing? **A.** Sorting based on matching content in the array. **B**: Creating fields in the document. Do you understand how I kind of get you mean **A** but your question "content" draws a conclusion towards **B**. So **A** or **B**?

Comment: "Each object has an array of servicePlans. I need to sort on the date of a specific servicePlan." So A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do dynamically do this via aggregate which can calculate a field to sort on, then this would be the most efficient way:

```js
var match = "x1";

db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "servicePlans": 1,
    "order": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$filter": {
          "input": "$servicePlans",
          "as": "sp",
          "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$sp._id",  match ] }
        }},
        0
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "order": -1 } }
])
```

This is returning everything, with anything unmatched returning `null` and listed afterwards in 'descending order' or before in 'ascending order' since that is how `null` sorts in comparison to a `Date`.

---

If you wanted to update the documents so you could simply choose a property to sort on with a regular find, then you could do this to update:

```js
let ops = [];

db.collection.find().forEach(doc => {

  let update = {};
  doc.servicePlans.forEach(plan => {
    update["servicePlan_" + plan._id] = plan.date;
  })

  ops = [
     ...ops,
     {
       "updateOne: {
         "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
         "update": { "$set": update }
       }
     }
  ];

  if ( ops.length >= 500 ) {
    db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
    ops = [];
  }

})

if ( ops.length > 0 )
  db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
```

Comment: This is great, just how I need it. The `{ "$eq": [ "$$sp._id": match ] }` has a typo, '`:`' instead of '`,`'. Thanks for the detailed explanation, gives a lot of insight on aggregating in mongo.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a bit of aggregation

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { "$unwind" : "$servicePlans" },
  { "$match" : { "servicePlans._id" : "x1" } },
  { "$sort" : { "servicePlans.date" : 1 } }
]);
```

This will give the result of:

```
{ "_id" : "2", "servicePlans" : { "_id" : "x1", "date" : "2017-01-01" } }
{ "_id" : "1", "servicePlans" : { "_id" : "x1", "date" : "2017-01-02" } }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Kevin, will the unmatched servicePlans be excluded from the output? Any way I can leave the servicePlans array in tact?

Comment: Instead of using the `{ "$match" : { "servicePlans._id" : "x1" } }` you could just join the documents back together with a "$groupby"